# Infinte loop adding elements in a list does not give OOME , why

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have tried using the below code of infinte loop

```
public class OOME_Collection {

    static List l = new ArrayList();
    static Long i= new Long(1) ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            l.add(i);
            i++;
            System.out.println("size " + l.size());
        }

    }
}
```

last SOP is : size 3310522
Why It does not give OOME error, and moreover heap size keep varying b/w 50 MB to 100 MB

Comment: Can't reproduce... I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` over here.

Comment: Heh, try `l.add(new Long(i));`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Agree that these are small objects, but I fail to understand that how come they are same. As per my understanding every time, a new Intger object is added to the List

Comment: @Naroji:  Technically, a new `Long` is being added to the list every time.

Comment: @Makoto: no. There is an `i++` inside the loop, and i is the Long object, which is thus replaced by a new one at each iteration.

Comment: @JBNizet:  I had modified the original code to see behavior, was looking at that when I made the remark.  My bad.

Comment: @JBNizet I am bit confused. Is not a new Long object added every time the loop is executed ?

Comment: @Naroji: yes, a new Long is added at each iteration. But printing to the console at each iteration takes a lot of time. Remove the System.out.println line, and you'll probably see an OOME much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have enough ram for garbace collector to do its job. Try to make it really big by adding more items before printing anything to the screen (displaying message is really slow, so you will wait reaaaally long for the OOME)

```
...

public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            for(int j=0;j<1000000;++j)
                l.add(i);
            i++;
            System.out.println("size " + l.size());
        }    
    }

...
```

this nicely throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2245)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:213)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:187)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:411)
    at test.Test.main(OOME.java:26)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: You forgot to declare `i`

Comment: I did not, this is just a change in the original code, where `i` is a static class variable

Comment: As you said : Probably you have enough ram for garbace collector to do its job, but my question is when the Integer objects are kept adding to the list(mean to say they have strong reference) then how a GC can collect and destroy these Integer Objects refereed from List

Comment: It does not destroy integer objects (in fact, there are no Integer objects here, there references Long objects, multiplicated milions of times), it destroys other variables allocated by the JVM. For example - there are dozens of temporal Strings produced for the System.out.println() command, and I guess many more weird data "under the hood". This is what you observe when looking for the allocated memory. All these variables are not referenced from the code,so GC cleans them up once space for new references in list is needed. Once it runs out of such objects - it throws OOME.

Comment: @lejlot: no. Each time `i++` is called, it replaces the static Long object by another, new one.

Comment: @lejlot thanks for the inputs and insight on the heap behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Your system might be having high processing powers and memory so that GC is working hard to reclaim the space as you can see memory consumption varying from 50 to 150MB.

You can form a graph of time it took to add 1000 objects, versus the count.
Then you may see some anomalies in the graph regularly which may conclude that during the anomaly time GC is working to reclaim the space. Just an approximation to conclude.